# How to make title for home to be News, but if page has parent then its name else just post/page name

Tags: pages, bloginfo

Made own template from scratch and tutorials.
This is showing description of post/page Title and in home its showing website name.

```
<h3><?php is_home() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></h3>
```

I wanted to change that if home page then that it writes News and if page then its name but if page is subpage then parent name.

Comment: w...o...w... that title is awesome. No, honestly: I don't get what you're after. Hint: The title should sum up what it is _about_, not the whole task in pseudo code.

Comment: Changed it :) but still how to make this questions title better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `functions.php`:

```
function my_title() {
    if (is_home())
        echo 'News';
    else {
        global $post;
        if ($post->post_parent)
            echo get_post($post->post_parent)->post_title;
        else echo $post->post_title;
    }
} // function my_title
```

and then use `<?php my_title(); ?>` anywhere you want.

The above code prints **News** on the home page, for child posts the name of their respective parent, and the post title otherwise.

If you want to do this **for pages only** (no other post types), then use this:

```
function my_title() {
    if (is_home())
        echo 'News';
    else {
        global $post;
        if ('page' === $post->post_type && $post->post_parent)
            echo get_post($post->post_parent)->post_title;
        else echo $post->post_title;
    }
} // function my_title
```

Comment: WOW. I start to understand php messing all the time with this my self made WP theme :)
From your answer i copied just inner part to my header.php between php tag for title:
    if (is_home())
        echo 'News';
    else {
        global $post;
        if ($post->post_parent)
            echo get_post($post->post_parent)->post_title;
        else echo $post->post_title;
    }

And that works Perfect! Thanks :)

Comment: Hm, that let's me think you only have an `index.php` template file, right? Maybe you should read a bit on [theme development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)...? Glad I could help, anyway. ;)

Comment: I started making WP theme own clean cause was wasting a lot time trying to make my tables to look correct using child eleven theme and then some blank themes. Then i started making own clean theme with just Header index and Footer. I understood that WP reads file named functions if exists and there can be put functions with defining their names but for now so that i can see all fixes and inspire for new from them ill keep it just in 3 files. And only this additional if differs Pages from other views that i hope is not taking a lot electricity to calculate. :) THX